# Scraping: issues receiving table data when looping with request

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup

UPDATE: 
The code only works momentarily. There are 2000+ cryptos and at this moment i have 492 unique files with their history.

When I try to run a url getting skipped in the first place on its own, it works. Therefore I think it has been narrowed down to have something to do with the request of content.

Is it possible to make sure the table i'm interested in is fully loaded before continuing the code?

UPDATE: 
I got it working properly. I think there is a limit of requests you can do per sec or min on the website im trying to scrape from. 
I put in a delay on 3 sec between every request and NOW IT WORKS!!!!
Thanks to both of you for the help. Even though it didn't provide a direct answer, it put me on the right track to figuring it out.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time

def scraping(url):
    global line
    content = requests.get(url).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'html.parser')
    table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'table'})
    if not table:
        print(url)
        return
    data = [[td.text.strip() for td in tr.findChildren('td')] for tr in table.findChildren('tr')]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df.drop(df.index[0], inplace=True) 
    df[0] =  pd.to_datetime(df[0])
    for i in range(1,7):
        df[i] = pd.to_numeric(df[i].str.replace(",","").str.replace("-",""))
    df.columns = ['Date','Open','High','Low','Close','Volume','Market Cap']
    df.set_index('Date',inplace=True)
    df.sort_index(inplace=True)
    return df.to_csv(line + '_historical_data.csv')


with open("list_of_urls.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        time.sleep(3)
        line = line.strip()
        start = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/"
        end = "/historical-data/?start=20000101&end=21000101"
        url = start + line + end
        scraping(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may perform `findChildren()` only of the returned `table` and `tr` objects are not `NoneType`, as follows:

```
data = [[td.text.strip() for td in tr.findChildren('td') if td] for tr in table.findChildren('tr') if tr] if table else []
if len(data) > 0:
    # process your data here
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Just tried it out. Same error. I got through the first 38 before i get the error. It seems so odd to me.

Comment: What about now (see my updated answer)? By adding `if table` and `if td`. Should work hopefully.

Comment: Hi, now it gives me this instead: "IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0" for this line "df.drop(df.index[0], inplace=True)"

Comment: Because you would need to skip processing if there are no td cells. Look at my updated answer. Hope it works now.

Answer (score 0):

it could be URL not found `404` or the page has no table. To debug normalize your loop and print current processing Crypto name

```
table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'table'})
if not table:
    print('no table')
    return
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much. It works better now (i got 207 files this time). Do you have any idea why it cant find the table in the skipped ones, because if i check the website it is there? Maybe even a solution to get the last 1500+ cryptos history?

Comment: If you want to inspect the differences (i dont think there is any), this got skipped: https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/commerceblock/historical-data/?start=20000101&end=21000101 and this worked: https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/?start=20000101&end=21000101

Comment: in my machice both return table, I think you need `sleep` between request